# Write a shell script to find the largest among three numbers. Get user inputs and display the result

Tags: bash, unix

Write a shell script to find the largest among three numbers. Get user inputs and display the result.

Sample input 1:

```
10
20
30
```

Sample output 1:

```
30 is largest number
```

Sample input 2:

```
10
10
10
```

Sample output 2:

```
All the three numbers are equal
```

Sample input 3:

```
10
10
1
```

Sample output 3:

```
I cannot figure out which number is largest
```

Bash code:

```
#!bin/bash
read a b c
if [ $a -eq $b -a $a -eq $c ]; then
    echo "All the three numbers are equal"
elif [[ $a -eq $b || $b -eq $c || $c -eq $a ]]; then
    echo "I cannot figure out which number is largest"
else
    if [ $a -gt $b -a $a -gt $c ]; then
        echo "$a is biggest number"
    elif [ $b -gt $a -a $b -gt $c ]; then
        echo "$b is biggest number"
    elif [ $c -gt $a -a $c -gt $b ]; then
        echo "$c is biggest number"
    fi
fi
```

Testcases to be passed: There are three test cases to be passed, but I am able to pass only one test case.

1. Different values (passed).
   [image: Passed test case]
2. Unique values (failed).
   [image: Failed test case]
3. Equal values (failed).
   [image: Failed test case]

Actual result when evaluating the code:

[image: Evaluation failed]

Note: Even though I am getting actual result as expected result which is mentioned in question, I am able to pass the only one test case (different values) and remaining two test cases (equal values and unique values) are failing. I am even unable to spot the error.

Some errors I got when I tried in these ways:

[image: Error while giving two equal values and one special character]
[image: Error while two different values and one special character as input]
[image: Error when giving less than 3 inputs]
[image: Error while giving more than 3 inputs]

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is here. What do you expect the code to do? What does it do that you don't want it to do?

Comment: And what is your question? `All three numbers are equal` - this is strange result, why not just print the biggest number? `I cannot figure out which number is larges` - sure you can, it's `10`, it's right there in the input.

Comment: To avoid the errors `integer expression expected` or `too many arguments` check your input before processing it. Instead of using `read a b c` read the whole line, then check and parse it. If you type more than 3 words, `c` will contain everything from the 3rd to the end of the line. If you type less than 3 words, the remaining variables will be empty. This or non-numeric values will break the `test` (`[`) commands or the arithmetic comparisons. Alternative implementation: `biggest=$a; [ $max -lt $b ] && max=$b; [ $max -lt $c ] && max=$c; echo $max is biggest number` or simply ...`echo $max`

Comment: one-liner to give the biggest number out of any number of entered numbers (integers or floats)`read -r a&&echo "The biggest number is: $(cut -d $'\n' -f1< <(sort -rn< <(tr ' ' \\n<<<"$a")))"`

Comment: Your problem is not with the logic in your script. How is the evaluation result determined, i.e. how do the test cases work?

Comment: Test cases will pass only when we get actual result same as expected result. What i think is that, there should be an other way to write this code, so that three test cases will be passed. One test cases is passed, that means i wrote correct syntax for it. And for the remaining two test cases, the code should be written in other way.

Answer (score 0):

```
read n1
read n2
read n3
if [[ $n1 == 0 || $n2 == 0 || $n3 == 0 ]]; then
    echo "command line arguments are missing"
elif [[ $n1 == $2 && $n2 == $n3 ]]; then
    echo "All the three numbers are equal"
elif [[ $n1 == $n2 || $n2 == $n3 || $n3 == $n1 ]]; then
    echo "I cannot figure out which number is biggest"
else
    if [[ $n1 > $n2 && $n1 > $n3 ]]; then 
        echo "$n1 is Biggest number"
    elif [[ $n2 > $n1 && $n2 > $n3 ]]; then
        echo "$n2 is Biggest number"
    else
        echo "$n3 is Biggest number"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: It is recommended to avoid code-only answer. It would be more helpful if you could edit it adding at least a minimal explanation about _how_ your solution works and _why_ it solves asker's issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in your code. It is in the echo statement. You have to print the exact statement Accenture asked in the description. Instead of biggest number, it should be largest number.

I too was stuck on this frustrating issue and finally realized where things were going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
read num1
read num2
read num3
if [ $num1 == $num2 -a $num1 == $num3 ]
then
 echo "All the three numbers are equal"
elif [ $num1 == $num2 -o $num1 == $num3 -o $num2 == $num3 ]
then
 echo "I cannot figure out which number is largest"
else
 if [ $num1 -gt $num2 -a $num1 -gt $num3 ]
 then
   echo "$num1 is largest numer"
 elif [ $num2 -gt $num1 -a $num2 -gt $num3 ]
 then
   echo "$num2 is largest number"
 else
   echo "$num3 is largest number"
 fi
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues. It took a little troubleshooting.

```
read v1
read v2
read v3

if [[ $v1 == $v2 && $v1 == $v3 ]]; then
    echo "All the three numbers are equal"
elif [[ $v1 == $v2 || $v2 == $v3 || $v3 == $v1 ]]; then
    echo "I cannot figure out which number is largest"
else
    if [[ $v1 > $v2 && $v1 > $v3 ]]; then
        echo "$v1 is largest number"
    elif [[ $v2 > $v3 && $v2 > $v1 ]]; then
        echo "$v2 is largest number"
    elif [[ $v3 > $v1 && $v3 > $v2 ]]; then
        echo "$v3 is largest number"
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

> passed all test cases

```
` 
read n1
read n2
read n3

if (( $n1==$n2 & $n2!=$n3 ))
then
  echo "I cannot figure out which number is largest"
elif (( $n1==$n2  &  $n1==$n3 ))
then 
 echo "All the three numbers are equal"
 else
   if (( $n1>=$n2 & $n1>=$n3 ))
   then
    echo "$n1 is largest number"
   elif (( $n2>=$n1 & $n2>=$n3 ))
   then
    echo "$n2 is largest number"
   else
    echo "$n3 is largest number"
 fi
fi`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
read n1
read n2
read n3
if [[ $n1 == $n2 && $n2 == $n3 ]]; then #Note : There should be space between $variable and == operator
    echo "All the three numbers are equal"
elif [[ $n1 == $n2 || $n2 == $n3 || $n1 == $n3 ]]; then
    echo "I cannot figure out which number is largest"
elif [[ $n1 > $n2 && $n1 > $n3 ]]; then
    echo "$n1 is largest number"
elif [[ $n2 > $n1 && $n2 > $n3 ]]; then
    echo "$n2 is largest number"
else
    echo "$n3 is largest number"
fi
```

Comment: Could you help to make this answer more useful by clarifying on why this would fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Accept any three numbers
,compare them using if loop
,print output using echo
[image: Used if loop only, you can use elif loop also]